# Java aspect for logging start/end of method

Tags: java, aspectj

I want to log when the method is executed and when the method ends. For this I have a simple aspect

```
@Aspect
public class StartEndLogger {
  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(StartEndLog)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
    Object result = null;
    System.out.println("start");
    try {
        result = point.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("end");
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then defined annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface StartEndLog {

}
```

For testing I have:

```
@StartEndLog
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
}
```

Thing is, the aspect does not intercept the method execution (runtime does not get in the aspect). Should I somehow register the aspect for this annotation? I do not use any Spring.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html

Comment: If the annotation has a package name you need to use the fully qualified name in the annotation-style pointcut. If you use native syntax this is not necessary, then you would just use an import.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

In the "META-INF/aop.xml" file of your jar, include the full path of your Aspect class

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <include within="somepackage.StartEndLogger " />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <concrete-aspect name="MyLoggingAspect"
         extends="somepackage.StartEndLogger">
            <pointcut name="around_logging" expression="execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(StartEndLog)"/>
        </concrete-aspect>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

If you were using spring framework, Annotate your class also with "@Component".

This is an extract from [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html):

> You may register aspect classes as regular beans in your Spring XML
>   configuration, or autodetect them through classpath scanning - just
>   like any other Spring-managed bean. However, note that the @Aspect
>   annotation is not sufficient for autodetection in the classpath: For
>   that purpose, you need to add a separate @Component annotation (or
>   alternatively a custom stereotype annotation that qualifies, as per
>   the rules of Spring’s  component scanner).